# What does the expression 'justified for him his own idea' mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence

I am reading a novel, and I did not understand one of the sentences in it. Following are two lines from the novel. The narrator is talking about a guy called Paul and her father.

> They were once caught in a three-week rainstorm, my father said if you could spend three weeks in a wet tent with a man without killing him or having him kill you then he was a good man. Paul justified for him his own idea of the simple life; but for Paul, the anachronism was imposed, he'd never chosen it.

I did not understand the last sentence - `Paul justified for him his own idea of the simple life; but for Paul, the anachronism was imposed, he'd never chosen it.`

Could someone explain it to me? From the context, I think that it means - 'My father liked Paul's simple life, but for Paul it wasn't an option'.

Comment: This quotation is extremely odd. It contains punctuation errors, vague allusions, grammatically questionable structures, and puzzling, inconsistent internal references. I am actually more than baffled by the whole thing. Is this a translation of a work originally written in a language other than English (and very badly translated)? Can you assure us that the text is accurate? I don't see any way to answer your question without a much improved text.

Comment: This means that the father already idealized "simple" living, and Paul's apparently simple lifestyle only affirmed his original feelings. Paul, however, seemingly didn't choose to live simply, and would perhaps have preferred a more ordinary (not simple) life. A link to the original, from *Surfacing* by Margaret Atwood: http://j.mp/17uCKxS

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg It seems once you sell a certain number of books, you can start using semi-colons and commas just exactly as you please. The grammar is hers, not OP's.

Comment: I have copied it as it is from Margaret Atwood's 'Surfacing'. Thanks, onomatomaniak for your answer.

Comment: @onomatomaniak  Good lord, really?? This is actually how Atwood wrote this?? It's an execrable mess! Thanks for saving me from ever trying to read anything by Margaret Atwood.

Comment: What would the text look like if it was corrected?

Comment: Apparently you have the text exactly as it was printed. Correction then becomes a debatable issue, because we would be discussing a writer's creative choices. I think the writing is just plain awful, but Atwood has the right to write that way if she wishes, and obviously she's published and popular. I could try to discuss some of the structure I find questionable, but what I'm trying to say is, my points would lose some validity since they would be criticism of a writer's prerogative. "I may not agree with what you say, but I will defend to the death your right to say it!"

Comment: This is a novel written in 1st person, so it's not correct to say "The author is talking about a guy called Paul and her father." This is not Atwood's father, it's the character's. The novel (at least the extract in onomatomaniak's link) is written in the present tense, which is itself unusual, & in the style of someone reminiscing. It's clearly colloquial & in a small town/rural setting. I think Atwood knew exactly what she was doing with her punctuation when she chose to evoke atmosphere in this way. Even supposing she didn't, you would surely rely on her publishing editor to correct errors?

Comment: @Mynamite Good points but have you ever read the story? I have never read it and am trying to find if it has been translated in Farsi/Persian or not however I know from the writer's biography that she has written many of her stories according to her real life.She was living with her father in Northern Canada in Quebec's forests and it can be reliable if OP considers it is about her father in the real life. Writers do not write the reality but surely not a complete fantasy. Even in most surreal forms of writing you can find signs of the writer's real life. No scape of the reality!

Comment: @PersianCat  That's very true, but if that's the case then all the more reason to believe that the punctuation was a deliberate attempt to transcribe the way people spoke as she remembers it. This is not a scientific paper or annual report, it's creative writing. People don't converse in perfect sentences. I think it's sad that John Landsberg condemns it an 'execrable mess' without having read the full thing in context. I also can't imagine why his comment has received 2 votes for 'adding something to this post'.

Comment: @Mynamite Agree with you. It is a kind of creative writing.

Comment: @PersianCat  I've just found [eye dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect) mentioned elsewhere on this site, it seems to be the same kind of thing.

Comment: @Mynamite But I do not see any misspelling here to refer it to the eye dialect trick! Maybe you mean a bad writing on purpose to describe a special character which is very usual in writings of serious writers that is not called eye dialect.

Comment: @PersianCat  Yes, I should have made that clearer! I meant the non-standard punctuation is all part of the characterisation.

Comment: @onomatomaniak:  I think you answered the OP's question quite well.  At least that's how I would have answered it, not being familiar with the context of the excerpt.  Good 'splaining!  (Sorry, I'm a child of the 50s.  In "I love Lucy," Lucy's Cuban husband would often say exasperatedly to Lucy, "Lucy, you've got some 'splaining to do!")

Answer (score 1):

Here Paul is explaining why his idea of what a simple life means is justified.

Justify means to prove that something is right or reasonable.

It is usually used in terms of morality, for example you could shock someone by saying:

'Paul told his father that he would shoot Mr X in the head'

This would be murder, we all accept murder is morally wrong. However if we knew that Mr X was just about to do something extremely terrible like kill an entire bus full of children..

'after explaining the situation to his father, Paul justified for him why he would do such a  thing'